# Hyperlink Based Charts?

Tags: links, latex, google-chart-api

I know that Google provides tex format mathematical equations: https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/formulas?hl=en in the form of a hyperlink.

If I'm doing a flowchart, does Google or someone provide a similar way to encode a flowchart into a weblink?